# How to Remove description text from product slider - Luma Theme

Tags: magento2, blocks, static-block, slider

Please check. **Luma Theme**

This one is from website Homepage Product tab
This is Product slider / carousel Magento - It's coming from block.

My question is - Can we remove description lines. If yes, then please suggest how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: which theme use ?

Answer (score 0):

Find code like this and remove from your slider PHTML file.

```
'<div class="product description">'
      . $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')
      . ' <a href="' . $_product->getProductUrl() . '" class="action more">'
      . __('Learn More') . '</a>'
.'</div>';
```

Comment: where will I find this file?

Comment: do you know slider PHTML file?

Comment: Hi this is Luma theme, and we are calling this from blocks

Comment: Ok, check in that block you will get `.phtml` file path OR share block content in your question.

Comment: Hi I found phtml now looking for block file

Comment: try to find `getShortDescription` in luma theme you will get PHTML.